# Rust: dyn Fn()` cannot be shared between threads safely

Tags: multithreading, rust

I study multithreads in Rust, find an error about use Fn in thread::spawn. My code like this:

```
use std::thread;

fn print_hello() {
    println!("hello");
}

fn run_fn(f: &dyn Fn()) {
    let hand = thread::spawn(move || {
        f();
    });
}

fn main() {
    run_fn(&print_hello);
}
```

After compiling, I get the following error:

```
   Compiling fntest v0.1.0 (D:\ray\source\rust\fntest)   
error[E0277]: `dyn Fn()` cannot be shared between threads safely
   --> src\main.rs:8:16
    |
8   |     let hand = thread::spawn(move || {
    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `dyn Fn()` cannot be shared between threads safely
    |
    = help: the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `dyn Fn()`
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Send` for `&dyn Fn()`
    = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src\main.rs:8:30: 10:6]`
note: required by a bound in `spawn`
   --> C:\Users\zhang\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\lib/rustlib/src/rust\library\std\src\thread\mod.rs:628:8
    |
628 |     F: Send + 'static,
    |        ^^^^ required by this bound in `spawn`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain 
E0277`.
error: could not compile `fntest` due to previous error
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the error note, you cannot use `&dyn Fn` because it is not `Send`. So, you could use some generics, constrained to what it is needed here, `Fn() + Send + 'static`:

```rust
use std::thread;

fn print_hello() {
    println!("hello");
}

fn run_fn<F: Fn() + Send + 'static>(f: F) {
    let _hand = thread::spawn(f);
}

fn main() {
    run_fn(&print_hello);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7baec76e7961e7c246bb5cae0ac33b45)